# AJAX Toolkit and Listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, ajaxcontroltoolkit

[image]I am working on a web application. The process regarding the problem is that I am fetching users comments from DB using Entity Framework Model. I am using a listview to show Customers Name, Rating and Comments.
The problem is that I am using a Ajax toolkit control called HTMLEditor for storing comments in the DB, so when I have to display the comments, I need the same control ie HTML Editor. Now when I use the following code to create the ITEMTEMPLATE for the listview,

```
 <ItemTemplate>
<tr style="background-color:#EDECB3;color: #000000;"> 
<td><%# Eval("CustomerName")%></td>
    <td> <img src='Styles/Images/ReviewRating<%# Eval("Rating") %>.png' alt="">
    <br />
    </td>
    <td> <cc1:Editor ID="Comments" runat="server" Text="<%#Eval("Comments") %>"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

Everything is working except the line

```
 <td> <cc1:Editor ID="Comments" runat="server" Text="<%#Eval("Comments") %>"/>
        </td>
```

It says that the server tag is not well formed. please help.

Updated Error: I added nounicode="true". and the error I encountered is

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or
>   the neutral culture.  Make sure
>   "AjaxControlToolkit.Properties.Resources.NET4.resources" was correctly
>   embedded or linked into assembly "AjaxControlToolkit" at compile time,
>   or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully
>   signed.

[image: Screenshot showing editor within listview]

Comment: Just to be sure, Have you tried to remove that tag and it worked? Sometimes the error may be generated by another section.

Comment: Yes its working.Its also working if i use no control and just the EVAL expression within the <td></td>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the ScriptManager on the page solve the problem. 
As far as the problem of displaying HTML text in HTML Editor is concerned, I decided not to use the HTML Editor from Ajax Control Toolkit. Rather I displayed the html text raw on the page using the html decoding utility like this,

```
<%#Server.HtmlDecode(Eval("Comments").ToString()) %>
```

Comment: And yes, the problem of not being able to display HTML data in an HTML Editor in a Listview stands as it was, unsloved.

Comment: you need to convert HTML data to plain text in your code behind file.

Comment: add this code and then check- <cc1:Editor ID="Comments" runat="server"/>

Comment: I think the editor shows up there but just like a small inactive coomponent, looks like an **8** to me.

Comment: <cc1:Editor ID="Editor1" runat="server" NoUnicode="true" /> try this

Comment: It didn't work, The situation remains same as in the second screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

you should try

```
<cc1:Editor ID="Comments" runat="server" Text="<%#Eval('Comments') %>"/>
```

the text proprty is not the same.

Comment: whats the difference? I also used TEXT.

Comment: the coma, try to use single quote instead of double. maybe

Comment: Sorry, It reported error, as there are too many characters in the character literal.

Comment: <cc1:Editor ID="Comments" runat="Server" Content='<%# Bind("Comments") %>'></asp:cc1:Editor> this should works

Comment: But this is the correct way to bind the Editor, what is the error exactly ?

Comment: Check updated question. Can this be a issue because I am using Ajax Control Toolkit Control(HTML Editor) inside a Listview? Maybe due to some compatibility issues?

Comment: please refer to [ajax toolkit html editor inside Listview](http://forums.asp.net/t/1461438.aspx/1)

Comment: FYI, I am encountering the error even if I dont use the EVAL expression. I tried setting Text="SAM" and Content="SAM" but it encountered the updated error. I think the error is not regarding code.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

Text='<%#Eval("Comments") %>'

Comment: i am not doing fun, i have just answered ur question.

Comment: please check if you have added the scriptmanager tag.    Please refer the article :   http://www.vijaykodali.com/Blog/post/2011/11/06/Make-sure-AjaxControlToolkitPropertiesResourcesNET4resources-was-correctly-embedded.aspx

Comment: Or it can be solved using this tag...       <ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" />

Comment: I added the criptmanager tag and it helped. The error went away but no text is appearing in that section where I want HTMLEDITOR. There appeas a special character like an **8** and nothing else.

Comment: Now try this and check - Content='<%#Bind("Comments") %>'

Comment: I said that before, because the property "Text" doesnot exist for htmlEditor and obviously the "scriptmanager" is obligatory when you use ajaxcontroltoolkit

Comment: Ok, tell me one thing, and please try to understand, eval("comments") returns me an HTML code, and I need HTMLEditor so that it can be parsed. Is there any other way to display HTML on page except this HTML EDITOR? If I display it just like that within the <td> tags it displays naked HTML which is not pleasing to read.

Comment: That will help too, But it would be good if HTML is rendered and then displayed. It should be displayed properly but I don't know why HTML tags are printed as they are.

Comment: Check the screenshot. Its displaying HTML code of comments instead of formatted comments.

Answer (score 0):

"rr_only4you" told that answer is correct, i got the error like use  blow one

Text="<%#Eval("Comments") %>"

after that i change that to

Text='<%# Eval("Comments") %>'

this format it will correct,

you use this one

<cc1:Editor ID="Comments" runat="server"><%# Eval("Comments") %></cc1>